# Class 'JMS\SerializerBundle\JMSSerializerBundle' not found

Tags: symfony

I'm trying to install JMSSerializerBundle on Symfony2. I followed the Composer instructions [here](http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSSerializerBundle/master/installation).

When I try to actually use JMSSerializerBundle, I get this:

```
Fatal error: Class 'JMS\SerializerBundle\JMSSerializerBundle' not found in /home/jason/pressbox/app/AppKernel.php on line 25
```

Here's my `AppKernel.php`:

```
<?php

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Loader\LoaderInterface;

class AppKernel extends Kernel
{
    public function registerBundles()
    {
        $bundles = array(
            new Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\SecurityBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\MonologBundle\MonologBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\SwiftmailerBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DoctrineBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\AsseticBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\DoctrineMigrationsBundle\DoctrineMigrationsBundle(),
            new Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\SensioFrameworkExtraBundle(),
            new JMS\SecurityExtraBundle\JMSSecurityExtraBundle(),
            new Stof\DoctrineExtensionsBundle\StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle(),
            new VNN\PressboxBundle\VNNPressboxBundle(),
            new VNN\SecurityBundle\VNNSecurityBundle(),
            new VNN\CoreBundle\VNNCoreBundle(),
            new JMS\SerializerBundle\JMSSerializerBundle($this),
        );

        if (in_array($this->getEnvironment(), array('dev', 'test'))) {
            $bundles[] = new Acme\DemoBundle\AcmeDemoBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\WebProfilerBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\SensioDistributionBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\GeneratorBundle\SensioGeneratorBundle();
        }

        return $bundles;
    }

    public function registerContainerConfiguration(LoaderInterface $loader)
    {
        $loader->load(__DIR__.'/config/config_'.$this->getEnvironment().'.yml');
    }
}
```

Did I miss something? What do I need to do to get it to work?

Comment: You've run `php composer.phar update` and it completed without error? (and cleared cache of course)

Comment: have you added the JMSSerializerBundle in your deps file and ran php bin\vendors install?

Comment: Yes, I had done the `composer.phar` thing. Adding JMSSerializerBundle to my `deps` file did the trick. @bernardnapoleon, if you put that as an answer, I'll accept it. I'm a little bit confused, though, because I thought the whole point of using Composer was so that you didn't have to mess with the `deps` file.

Comment: I'm not familiar with composer.. =(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you added the JMSSerializerBundle in your deps file and ran php bin\vendors install?

Answer (score 0):

If you have manually installed the bundle, try to find out that the bundles files are really located at vendor/../JMS/SerializerBundle but not in vendor/../JMS/SerializerBundle/JMSSerializerBundle.

(I also faced the same error but resolved it by fixing it like I said)